# Contact Form Validation

Tags: validation, contact-form

I have a working contact form, with capcha to slow automated submissions.  It also allows submission of image files.  All is well except we're still getting plenty of spam submissions.

What I want to do is add a validation to the comment field that gives an erroneous error message (like: Your form can not be processed at this time.), whenever someone adds a clickable link (beginning with "http://") to the comment section.

I'm new to this but it seems like it should be fairly straightforward to disallow "http://".

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a regex to check if comment contains a URL, the following regex should work

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/;
```

http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the also you can look for more detailed explanation in this link.